# find a list of keywords from a text string and find inexact matches

Tags: python, django

I have a list of keywords I'm trying to find in a text string. The exact matches works fine but is anyone aware of library that could help with approximate matches so for instance if the list of words I provide are
`["hello", "bye"]`
I'd like it to watch if the text string has `hlelo` to a certain degree of "closeness"
Any recommendations?

Comment: Try using the term "Levenshtein distance" in searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do. First, define a string to search in and remove extraneous characters:

```
>>> tosearch = "This is a text string where I typed hlelo but I meant to type hello."
>>> import string
>>> exclude = set(string.punctuation)
>>> tosearch = ''.join(ch for ch in tosearch if ch not in exclude)
>>> tosearch
'This is a text string where I typed hlelo but I meant to type hello'
>>> words = set(tosearch.split(" "))
```

Next, you can use the [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) library to find close matches to a given word:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('hello', words)
['hello', 'hlelo']
```